# Reusing a recyclerview in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am calling the following method to populate a recyclerview in my Android app:

```
private void getDirectoriosFromDB(int id) {

        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... addressesIds) {
              //  Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "UID REGISTRADO ANTES DE CARGAR REECYCLER: " + user_id);



                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://...directorio_todos.php")
                        .build();
                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("HOLA ADDRESSES", "DIRECCION LEIDA: " + i);
                        Directorio directorio = new Directorio(object.getInt("id_directorio"),
                                object.getString("nombre"),
                                object.getString("apellidos"),
                                object.getString("apodo"),
                                object.getString("cumple"),
                                object.getString("conyuge"),
                                object.getString("cumple_conyuge"),
                                object.getString("aniversario_bodas"),
                                object.getString("empresa"),
                                object.getString("direccion_empresa"),
                                object.getString("tel_negocio"),
                                object.getString("fecha_ingreso"),
                                object.getString("num_rotario"),
                                object.getString("padrino"),
                                object.getString("direccion_casa"),
                                object.getString("tel_casa"),
                                object.getString("celular"),
                                object.getString("email"),
                                object.getString("clasificacion"),
                                object.getString("imagen")
                                );

                        directorios.add(directorio);
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        asyncTask.execute(id);
    }
```

Now I have included a search function to filter the data.

Once the user enters the search string, I want the recyclerview to only show the filtered items, but it doesn´t work, the recyclerview doesn´t change its content.

What should I do to refreh the recyclerview with the new content?

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully implemented search, then do the following,

```
// Update your adapter collection with the filtered data.
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: I assume that the collection content in your adapter have no change even after the search has completed and `recycleView` will do it's job with the same collection at the initial state.